# Sequelize in Nodejs creating duplicate tables upon app start

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Ok. Landscape: Node, MySql, Sequelize

Issue: After creating a new data model & migration (node migrate.js which creates just fine), upon app start Sequelize creates a duplicate Table (and also forwards form data to the new table).

Ex: db.virtual_class is the main table, and upon start, db.virtual_classes is also created.

My model:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../sequelize');

const model = sequelize.define('virtual_class', {
  id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true }, 
  style: Sequelize.STRING, // e.g. Style of class
  description: Sequelize.STRING(1024), // e.g. class Details
  jwt_secret: Sequelize.STRING, // e.g. rando string to be used to gen unique keys for every room
});

module.exports = model;
```

I've isolated what I think is the issue - I'm including the model in a variable on my index controller for my functions.

```
const Virtual_class = require('./model');
const classQuery = require('./classQuery');

async function addClass({ style, description, secret }) {
    const vClass = await Virtual_class.create({
      style,
      description,
      jwt_secret: secret,
    }, { raw: true });

    return classQuery(vClass);
}

module.exports = {
    addClass,
};
```

Class Query function to return the data in a usable object:

```
function classQuery(queryResult) {
    if (!queryResult) {
      return null;
    }

    return {
      id: queryResult.id,
      style: queryResult.style,
      description: queryResult.description,
      secret: queryResult.jwt_secret,
    };
  }

  module.exports = classQuery;
```

and the migration:

```
module.exports = {
    up: (sequelize, Sequelize) => sequelize.getQueryInterface().createTable('virtual_class', {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
      },
      style: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      description: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      jwt_secret: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      createdAt: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.fn('now'),
      },
      updatedAt: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.fn('now'),
      },
    }),

    down: sequelize => sequelize.getQueryInterface().dropTable('virtual_class'),
  };
```

Net result is fine before I run app - DB shows new table, After running app - DB shows dup table.

[image: DB TABLE VIEW]

I'm a relative noob, and been wracking my brain (and trying to find solutions here) to the problem. I've done this before with other migrations with no issue.

Any advice is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

DOH! For those who are new like me - Sequelize automatically creates plural tables by default, You can force the override tp singular table names.

Answer (score 0):

Use the flag "freezeTableName: true" to stop creating duplicate tables.

https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-basics/